# Pandas .loc doesn't work after using a regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data:

```
player  pos avg
0   Antonio Brown   WR1 1.0
1   Julio Jones (11)    WR2 2.3
2   Odell Beckham Jr. (13)  WR3 2.8
3   Todd Gurley (11)    RB1 4.8
4   DeAndre Hopkins (9) WR4 5.8
... ... ... ...
546 Kai Forbath (7) K31 538.0
547 Cody Parkey K32 539.0
548 Wil Lutz (5)    K33 542.0
549 Andrew Franks   K34 543.0
550 Caleb Sturgis   K35 544.0
```

I used the following regex code to get rid of parenthesis and all characters inside them:

```
df['player'] = df['player'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

Which got me what I wanted:

```
player  pos adp
0   Antonio Brown   WR1 1.0
1   Julio Jones WR2 2.3
2   Odell Beckham Jr.   WR3 2.8
3   Todd Gurley RB1 4.8
4   DeAndre Hopkins WR4 5.8
... ... ... ...
546 Kai Forbath K31 538.0
547 Cody Parkey K32 539.0
548 Wil Lutz    K33 542.0
549 Andrew Franks   K34 543.0
550 Caleb Sturgis   K35 544.0
```

However now when I use .loc, nothing shows up!

```
df.loc[(df.player=='Julio Jones')]


player  pos adp pos_adp season
```

But when I use .loc on a column that didn't originally have any parenthesis, it does work:

```
df.loc[(df.player=='Antonio Brown')]

player  pos adp pos_adp season
0   Antonio Brown   WR1 1.0 1   2016
```

This is so frustrating, why doesn't .loc work if I effectively used regex on the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `"Julio Jones (11)"` became `"Julio Jones "` and not `"Julio Jones"` after the replace, because you got rid of `"(11)"`, not `" (11)"`. I suggest you use `df.player.str.strip()` to get rid of the trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I added a space in the loc: df.loc[(df.player=='Julio Jones ')] and still nothing came up. I'll try .strip() right now. EDIT: Strip worked. This is an absolute lifesaver on so many levels. Thank you so much. Do you have any idea why using .loc with the space at the end doesn't work? Essentially I am searching for the exact value in the column...

Comment: Nice. I am not sure, but maybe it didn't work because that space in your data is not a regular space, but a special character.